# Form Design: How to best display/add different statuses?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am working on a rails form. Essentially, a person can have multiple statuses and switch between the different statuses. In database table, the display will be simple as follows:

```
status start_date end_date
work   1/1/15     1/10/15
sick   1/11/15    2/15/15
work   2/16/15    3/15/15
sick   1/15/15    1/14/15
```

I need to prompt user to input these information. I have made a status class which belongs to a person class. So basically, these fields will be a part of nested forms. 
My question is: How can I dynamically display these information to make forms elegant and clean to use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your domain, your `Person` has many `Status`, right?

The simplest way to do it is use the [gem cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon). Your view will look like this:

```
<%= form_for @person do |person_form| %>
  <%= person_form.input :name %>

   <%= person_form.fields_for :statuses do |status_form| %>
     <%= status_form.field :start_date, :end_date %>

     <!-- cocoon's method to dynamically add nested forms -->
     <%= link_to_add_association 'add status', person_form, :statuses
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks! I will play with cocoon. I have tried cocoon and it failed me before...any tricky parts I need to be aware of? I am trying to make user experience as dynamic as possible.

Comment: cocoon have a good documentation at its home page. Start with simpler form to understand how gem works